# Looping Through Group of Lines in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a key,value pair by parsing two specific lines in a line group from an audio analysis log, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to group a set of lines per file being analyzed. I'm looking for key,val from "Loading..." line and "Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames..." line.

```
8799 Songs Remaining 
Loading /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#4 falling.mp3
Detected sample rate: 44100 Hz, duration: 168.097959 seconds.
Using transform length of 13000 for FFT, which gives us 6501 bins at 3.392308 Hz per bin.
Detecting deep bass as peaks between 0.000000 Hz and 40.707692 Hz above -22 dB chosen from frequency range below 220.500000 Hz.
Estimated tempo: 132.512019.
Number of beats detected: 368.
Total frames: 2281, about 0.073695 seconds per frame
Number of deep beats: 19
Percentage of deep beats: 0.051630 
Number of frames with deep bass: 707.
Number of adjacent frames with deep bass: 287.
Number of deep bass frames per beat: 1.921196
Percentage of deep bass frames: 0.309952 
Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: 0.125822 
--- 17.513960123062134 seconds ---
8798 Songs Remaining  
Loading /Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#OccupyHipHop Inst.mp3
Detected sample rate: 44100 Hz, duration: 223.255805 seconds.
Using transform length of 13000 for FFT, which gives us 6501 bins at 3.392308 Hz per bin.
Detecting deep bass as peaks between 0.000000 Hz and 40.707692 Hz above -22 dB chosen from frequency range below 220.500000 Hz.
Estimated tempo: 114.843750.
Number of beats detected: 403.
Total frames: 3030, about 0.073682 seconds per frame
Number of deep beats: 28
Percentage of deep beats: 0.069479 
Number of frames with deep bass: 1302.
Number of adjacent frames with deep bass: 911.
Number of deep bass frames per beat: 3.230769
Percentage of deep bass frames: 0.429703 
Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: 0.300660 
--- 26.676011085510254 seconds ---
```

The result I'm looking for:

/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#OccupyHipHop Inst.mp3, 0.125822

/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#4 falling.mp3, 0.300660

Comment: please show us the code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

Regex:

```
(?m)^Loading\s(.*)[\s\S]*?Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames:\s(.*)[\s\S]*?(?=[\n\r]+Loading|\Z)
```

Regex demo [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/7Z9Smk/1)

```
import re
with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = dict(re.findall(r'(?m)^Loading\s(.*)[\s\S]*?Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames:\s(.*)[\s\S]*?(?=[\n\r]+Loading|\Z)', f.read()))
  print(data)
```

Output:

```
{"/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#4 falling.mp3": '0.125822 ', "/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/Jonas's iTunes/#OccupyHipHop Inst.mp3": '0.300660 '}
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?m)^` Asserts multi-line matching, and position at beginning of line
- `Loading\s` Matches Loading followed by a whitespace character
- `(.*)` Matches anything but a newline character (***this is your Volume line***)
- `[\s\S]*?` Matches any 0+ chars, as few as possible up until...
- `Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames:\s` Matches your desired percentage line, a colon, and a whitespace character
- `(.*)` Matches any anything but a newline character (***this is your percentage***)
- `[\s\S]*?` Matches any 0+ chars, as few as possible up until...
- `(?=[\n\r]+Loading|\Z)` This is your Loading pattern, using positive lookahead

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the lines: check if they start with what you are interested in; for the interesting lines take the slice that you want.

```
d = {}
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('Loading '):
        line = line.strip()
        # len('Loading ') --> 8
        key = line[9:]
    elif line.startswith('Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: '):
        line = line.strip()
        # len('Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: ') --> 41
        value = line[42:]
        print((key,value))
        d[key] = value
        key, value = '',''
```

---

Relies on the sequence of lines being predictable:

```
 key line,
 other lines,
 value line,
 other lines,
 key line,
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working using wwii's answer:

```
d = {}
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('Loading '):
        line = line.strip()
        key = line[9:]
        count = count + 1
    elif line.startswith('Percentage of adjacent deep bass frames: '):
        line = line.strip()
        value = line[42:]
        value = float(value)
        if value >= .4:
            print(key,value)
            d[key] = value
print("Total Tracks:",count)
print("Deep Bass Tracks:",len(d))
print("Percentage of total:",(len(d) / count))
```